# Start GUI application using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to open a file through python that once it is open takes you to a GUI. The link works fine when i just click on it and python seems to locate the file and open it, but the GUI doesn't appear. Please help. This is whay i have been using.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("C:/full/path")
```

I get no track back errors, but the GUI doesn't appear. Thoughts of how I can get it to appear, or what the problem might be?

Thanks

Comment: This code does not have anything to do with a gui. If your problem is your gui code, show us your gui code.

Comment: I am just trying to get python to act as if it is clicking the link and just bring up the GUI. Just as if I was clicking on the link on my desktop.

Comment: He's trying to start an application (which has a gui) as a subprocess. Providing more information about that application would be helpful, though.

Comment: use the command something like `start notepad myfile.txt`, in the subprocess.Popen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file you're trying to 'start' is a cmd script. Use this code:

```
subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe /k C:\full\path\to\file.cmd")
```

.cmd files are not executable by themselves - you need to invoke `cmd.exe` to execute them. This is also what windows does when you double-click the file on the desktop.

Comment: I have used OS.startfile before and it seems to start the file but the GUI doesn't seem to work. I can't get the Popen to work either. Sorry new to python

Comment: What kind of 'file' is it? You can only 'start' executable files.

Comment: To be more specific: What is it's name and extension, what does it contain and which application is it associated with?

Comment: extension is .cmd, sorry not much more. it is a 3rd party app.

Comment: When I run that now I just get windows system 32 screen with it set at c:\python27.

Comment: oh, 
I see. I forgot the /k switch. I corrected the answer again.

Comment: Now this.... The file name, directory name or volume label syntax incorrect. Bad path? or something else I checked path bout 5 times

Comment: Does the path contain spaces? then you need to wrap it in quotes. Also, on windows the path separator is `\ `, (but `/` should actually work, too)